# Артефакты в тексте на андроиде

Tags: android, html

```html
 <div class="b-facts__cart">
    <div class="b-facts__title">12</div>
    <div class="b-text b-text_black">В нашей команде 12 штатных сотрудников, которые были многократными призёрами</div>
</div>
```

Проект - обычный сайт.
Открыв в симуляторе андроида Samsung Galaxy S6 - (5.0.0 версия андроида), появляются артефакты, как это поправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в `штатных сотрудников` обычный пробел, мб используете какое-то хитрое форматирование через скрипты?

Comment: Очень похоже что у вас в строке присутствует [End Of Transmission](http://www.codetable.net/hex/4) символ. Правда я с таким сталкивался только на IOS, но думаю на андроиде он так же не пережевывается.